# start a service when a port is requested

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I have a program that runs on a certain door, listening to calls.

I created a .sh that runs this service and passes the parameters I need.

What I want is for my .sh to be executed when a request arrives at the door, not for it to be running all the time. That's because I'm running on the aws server, and I want to decrease the flow of demand for activities running, so I want to run something lighter just to hear the door, and then when something arrives, start my service which is heavier.

Does anyone know how to do this on ubuntu?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164497/start-a-service-on-a-network-request-socket-activation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netcat might work:

```
nc -l -p 7777 -e your-script.sh
```

It will listen to port 7777 and execute your-script.sh when a connection is established.

Comment: how do I pass the full path of my .sh script?

Comment: I tried nc -l -p 25565 -e /home/ubuntu/run.sh, but the option -e is invalid